# 2 various UIPanGestureRecognizers with different directions simultaneously?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer, simultaneous

It is possible to pan up, down, left and right.

Recognizer 1 handles vertical pans only, recognizer 2 handles horizontal pans only. Both of them are linked with the same one delegate object.

Recognizer 2 is fully independent from the first one (except of only one direction from the described 4 ones may be chosen).

So how to prevent one of them from being executed simultaneously with another one?

Comment: What sort of gesture recognizers are Recognizer 1 or 2 currently?

Comment: Are they UISwipeGestureRecognizers or UIPanGestureRecognizers? (Your title and question seem to conflict on this regard.)

Comment: pan gesture recognizer and another pan gesture recognizer. Read the question attentively please. Part marked with "P.S." is addition only. You don't need to read it if it confuses you

Comment: There's not a single mention of a UIPanGestureRecognizer in your actual question FYI...only in your title. You only mention UISwipeGestureRecognizer in your actual question:  "If it may be useful in my case I replace UISwipeGesture..."

Comment: I have deleted the part which confused you. Now `UIPanGesture` s are mentioned in question only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)initPanGestures{
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                action:@selector(handlePan1Gesture:)];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                        action:@selector(handlePan2Gesture:)]
}

-(void)handlePan1Gesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{
CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:sender.view];

switch(sender.state) {

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        if(fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x)){
            panGestureRecognizer2.enabled=YES;
            panGestureRecognizer1.enabled=NO;
        }
        break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
         panGestureRecognizer1.enabled=YES;
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:{
        panGestureRecognizer1.enabled=YES;
    }

        break;
}

if(velocity.x > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"gesture went right");
}
else if(velocity.x < 0)
{
    NSLog(@"gesture went left");
}


}

-(void)handlePan2Gesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{
 CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:sender.view];
switch(sender.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        if(fabs( velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y)){
            panGestureRecognizer2.enabled=NO;
            panGestureRecognizer1.enabled=YES;

        }
        break;

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        panGestureRecognizer2.enabled=YES;
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
         panGestureRecognizer2.enabled=YES;
        break;

}


if(velocity.y > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"gesture went down");
}
else if(velocity.y < 0)
{
    NSLog(@"gesture went up");
}

 }
```

Also For two diff Gesture you have to implement delegate methods and recognise the gestures.Fro example i have used two gesture simultaneously long and pan gesture

```
#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

return YES;
}

 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
if ([panGestureRecognizer1 isEqual:gestureRecognizer]) {

    return [panGestureRecognizer2 isEqual:otherGestureRecognizer];
}

if ([panGestureRecognizer2 isEqual:gestureRecognizer]) {

    return [panGestureRecognizer1 isEqual:otherGestureRecognizer];
}

return NO;
 }
```

Comment: Not quite right since it doesn't prevent the gestures from being executed simultaneously.

Comment: The `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` part of your answer is the only part that's relevant to this particular question... (i.e. What's `self.selectedItemIndexPath?`)

Comment: i think the handlePan is for handling direction,which was asked above Question and for handling mulitple gesture simultaneously shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer part is der, and the above code is just an example to understand.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but (1) if the swipe is on a diagonal, both if conditions will be met and (2) if the OP is in fact using a UISwipeGestureRecognizer, chances are he/she is setting its direction like so: `swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;` for example

Comment: The problem seems almost to be solved to make this answer approved but:
1)you forgot about the following: "Recognizer 1 handles vertical pans only, recognizer 2 handles horizontal pans only." fix the first part of your code please
2)I can't understand what do you want to do with `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`. It seems extra because you prevent one gesture from being executed at all.

Comment: please check the edit answer.hope this works for you